# How to breakpoint multiple C++ template methods, just like non templates?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

If I do:

```
(gdb) b nmspace::TestClass::compareFOO
```

Then the following methods signatures will be signed as a break point:

```
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOO(blah::Foo const&, blah::Foo const&, unsigned int)
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOO(blah::Foo const&, blah::FooField const&, unsigned int)
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOO(blah::FooField const&, blah::Foo const&, unsigned int)
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOO(blah::FooField const&, blah::FooField const&, unsigned int)
```

Is there something similar to the following or we must write the four everytime for template methods? Isn't polymorphism also applied to C++ templates?

```
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES<blah::Foo, blah::Foo>
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES<blah::Foo, blah::FooField>
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES<blah::FooField, blah::Foo>
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES<blah::FooField, blah::FooField>
```

I've tried `nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES`, `nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES*`, `nmspace::TestClass::compareFOOES<>()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if body of all of the function is same you may write a global function that can accept multiple type of parameters using `std::enable_if` or `boost::enable_if`:

```
template< class T >
struct is_valid_field
    : boost::or_<boost::is_same<T, blah::Foo>, boost::is_same<T, blah::FooField>>
{
};

template< class T, class Q >
nmspace::TestClass::compareFOO(T const&, Q const&, unsigned int,
    typename boost::enable_if<
        boost::and_<is_valid_field<T>, is_valid_field<Q>
    >::type* = 0)
{
    // implementation
}
```